# How to check if string is available on https page via command line on windows?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, openssl, wget

I suppose this is a simple question ,but I'm not sure how to proceed.
I want to check if a given string is available on a certain https address via command line.

In fact I can use Internet Explorer as a https client with VBScript , but this is not an option when command must be executed on a remote machine and I have no alive UI session (mstsc/netmeeting and etc.)

So:

1. I don't care if the check is performed with vbs/powershell/external command line tools.
2. I've exported certificate - so could I somehow use netcat+openSSL ?
3. I've tried to download the content of the page with bitsadmin to be used for further decryption but it didn't work. Will be wget for windows more useful here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I get it.
If anybody else  need this here's one way:

1. You need a wget compiled with ssl client .Here you have one option:
   http://users.ugent.be/~bpuype/wget/

2.You need extracted certificate for the needed site.Here's explained how this can be done with internet explorer:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788967.aspx

3.After you have imported the certificate to a some file you can execute following command:

```
wget --secure-protocol=auto --no-check-certificate --certificate=C:\file.cer  https://address
```

and this will download the page content